# Crypto++ and Compressed EC keys

Tags: c++, crypto++

How can I generate compressed ECDSA keys in Crypto++?

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
ECDSA<ECP, SHA1>::PrivateKey privateKey;
ECDSA<ECP, SHA1>::PublicKey publicKey;
privateKey.Initialize( prng, CryptoPP::ASN1::secp256r1());

const Integer& x1 = privateKey.GetPrivateExponent();
cout << "priv:  " << std::hex << x1 << endl;
privateKey.MakePublicKey( publicKey );
const ECP::Point& q = publicKey.GetPublicElement();
const Integer& qx = q.x;
const Integer& qy = q.y;
cout << "pub x: " << std::hex << qx << endl;
cout << "pub y: " << std::hex << qy << endl;
```

This code generates a keypair and prints the X and Y components of the public key.

I need to know if there is a way to print the Y component of the compressed key, or if I need to generate it from the uncompressed y component. If I need to generate it, can someone link me to a good explanation of how to work with the Integer class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I generate compressed ECDSA keys in CryptoPP?

You don't create a compressed key. You generate a public key, and then you compress it if that's what is required. From [How to construct a public ECDSA key with point compression turned on?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/f1XFx9CqUyg/inqFGB5O580J) on the Crpyto++ user group:

```
ECDSA<ECP, SHA1>::Verifier verifier(...);
verifier.AccessKey().AccessGroupParameters().SetPointCompression(true);
```

In your case, it will be:

```
publicKey.AccessGroupParameters().SetPointCompression(true);
```

since `verifier.AccessKey()` returns the ECDSA public key.

---

> I need to know if there is a way to print the Y component of the compressed key

Compression is a presentation format option or optimization. You can't print the Y component on a serialized key with compression because its not there (see the ASN.1 dumps below).

With compression on, the Y "shorthand" is going to be 1 or -1, depending on the sign of the component (the sign indicates what quadrant the point is in). The idea is someone sends you a {1,X} pair or {-1,X} pair and you can solve for Y because you know which quadrant it should be in. If Y is only allowed to be positive, you only need to serialize {X} (and not {-1,X} or {1,X}). (I did not dive into the books or standards, so there may be some errata here).

---

> ... or if I need to generate it from the uncompressed y component. If I need to generate it, can someone link me to a good explanation of how to work with the Integer class?

I have no idea what you're talking about at here. Point compression affects presentation. If you turn on point compression and fetch Y, you will still get Y out. You can't compute on a compressed point. You need the X and Y coordinates.

---

Add the following to your program:

```
publicKey.AccessGroupParameters().SetPointCompression(false);
ByteQueue q1;
publicKey.Save(q1);
cout << "Uncompressed size: " << dec << q1.MaxRetrievable() << endl;

publicKey.AccessGroupParameters().SetPointCompression(true);
ByteQueue q2;
publicKey.Save(q2);
cout << "Compressed size: " << dec << q2.MaxRetrievable() << endl;
```

Here's what I got for the output:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
priv:  4ce30d22d9593d9c7f4406eda1ce0740c7486106374d0abe7e352e1d5b1d5622h
pub x: 41a9bc936b6d1dd3a1ded997d7da08f1df990e9b50f9b58e9e4fd9319758ea34h
pub y: 4ad39ffb79c402063a99ecbc0cac8fde606db6764ace90933feee5f8d65937a2h
Uncompressed size: 311
Compressed size: 246
```

If you fetch Y after turning on point compression, you will still get 4ad39ffb79c402063a99ecbc0cac8fde606db6764ace90933feee5f8d65937a2h because compression affects presentation.

---

Now, add the following to dump the uncompressed and compressed key:

```
FileSink fs1("key-1.der", true);
q1.TransferTo(fs1);

FileSink fs2("key-2.der", true);
q2.TransferTo(fs2);
```

The keys are dumped in ASN.1's DER encoding and conform to Certicom's [SEC 1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://www.secg.org/collateral/sec1_final.pdf) (and to a lesser extent, [ANSI 9.62](ftp://ftp.iks-jena.de/mitarb/lutz/standards/ansi/X9/x962-11-17-97.pdf) and [RFC 5480, ECC SubjectPublicKeyInfo Format](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5480.txt) - see below on the Field Element's `OCTET STRING` vs `BIT STRING`).

You can run Peter Gutmann's [`dumpasn1`](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/dumpasn1.c%E2%80%8E) on them:

```
$ dumpasn1.exe key-1.der 
  0 307: SEQUENCE {
  4 236:   SEQUENCE {
  7   7:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER ecPublicKey (1 2 840 10045 2 1)
 16 224:     SEQUENCE {
 19   1:       INTEGER 1
 22  44:       SEQUENCE {
 24   7:         OBJECT IDENTIFIER prime-field (1 2 840 10045 1 1)
 33  33:         INTEGER
       :           00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
       :           00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
       :           FF
       :         }
 68  68:       SEQUENCE {
 70  32:         OCTET STRING
       :           FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
       :           00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FC
104  32:         OCTET STRING
       :           5A C6 35 D8 AA 3A 93 E7 B3 EB BD 55 76 98 86 BC
       :           65 1D 06 B0 CC 53 B0 F6 3B CE 3C 3E 27 D2 60 4B
       :         }
138  65:       OCTET STRING
       :         04 6B 17 D1 F2 E1 2C 42 47 F8 BC E6 E5 63 A4 40
       :         F2 77 03 7D 81 2D EB 33 A0 F4 A1 39 45 D8 98 C2
       :         96 4F E3 42 E2 FE 1A 7F 9B 8E E7 EB 4A 7C 0F 9E
       :         16 2B CE 33 57 6B 31 5E CE CB B6 40 68 37 BF 51
       :         F5
205  33:       INTEGER
       :         00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
       :         FF BC E6 FA AD A7 17 9E 84 F3 B9 CA C2 FC 63 25
       :         51
240   1:       INTEGER 1
       :       }
       :     }
243  66:   BIT STRING
       :     04 41 A9 BC 93 6B 6D 1D D3 A1 DE D9 97 D7 DA 08
       :     F1 DF 99 0E 9B 50 F9 B5 8E 9E 4F D9 31 97 58 EA
       :     34 4A D3 9F FB 79 C4 02 06 3A 99 EC BC 0C AC 8F
       :     DE 60 6D B6 76 4A CE 90 93 3F EE E5 F8 D6 59 37
       :     A2
       :   }

$ dumpasn1.exe key-2.der 
  0 243: SEQUENCE {
  3 204:   SEQUENCE {
  6   7:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER ecPublicKey (1 2 840 10045 2 1)
 15 192:     SEQUENCE {
 18   1:       INTEGER 1
 21  44:       SEQUENCE {
 23   7:         OBJECT IDENTIFIER prime-field (1 2 840 10045 1 1)
 32  33:         INTEGER
       :           00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
       :           00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
       :           FF
       :         }
 67  68:       SEQUENCE {
 69  32:         OCTET STRING
       :           FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
       :           00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FC
103  32:         OCTET STRING
       :           5A C6 35 D8 AA 3A 93 E7 B3 EB BD 55 76 98 86 BC
       :           65 1D 06 B0 CC 53 B0 F6 3B CE 3C 3E 27 D2 60 4B
       :         }
137  33:       OCTET STRING
       :         03 6B 17 D1 F2 E1 2C 42 47 F8 BC E6 E5 63 A4 40
       :         F2 77 03 7D 81 2D EB 33 A0 F4 A1 39 45 D8 98 C2
       :         96
172  33:       INTEGER
       :         00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
       :         FF BC E6 FA AD A7 17 9E 84 F3 B9 CA C2 FC 63 25
       :         51
207   1:       INTEGER 1
       :       }
       :     }
210  34:   BIT STRING
       :     02 41 A9 BC 93 6B 6D 1D D3 A1 DE D9 97 D7 DA 08
       :     F1 DF 99 0E 9B 50 F9 B5 8E 9E 4F D9 31 97 58 EA
       :     34
       :   }
```

Notice the differences:

```
# key-1.der
243  66:   BIT STRING
       :     04 41 A9 BC 93 6B 6D 1D D3 A1 DE D9 97 D7 DA 08
       :     F1 DF 99 0E 9B 50 F9 B5 8E 9E 4F D9 31 97 58 EA
       :     34 4A D3 9F FB 79 C4 02 06 3A 99 EC BC 0C AC 8F
       :     DE 60 6D B6 76 4A CE 90 93 3F EE E5 F8 D6 59 37
       :     A2
```

versus:

```
# key-2.der
210  34:   BIT STRING
       :     02 41 A9 BC 93 6B 6D 1D D3 A1 DE D9 97 D7 DA 08
       :     F1 DF 99 0E 9B 50 F9 B5 8E 9E 4F D9 31 97 58 EA
       :     34
       :   }
```

The first has two Integers encoded, while the second has one Integer encoded. The common value is `41 A9 BC 93 ... 97 58 EA 34`, and that's your `pub x` above. The missing string from key-2 is `4A D3 9F FB ... D6 59 37 A2`, and that's the `pub y` above. For completeness, the values are encoded as either {X,Y} or {X}, and not ASN.1's encoding of integers.

The final difference is the **first** octet of the BIT STRING: 02 versus 04 (or 03). 04 indicates its an uncompressed point. From RFC 5480, Section 2.2:

> ```
>     The first octet of the OCTET STRING indicates whether the key is
>     compressed or uncompressed.  The uncompressed form is indicated
>     by 0x04 and the compressed form is indicated by either 0x02 or
>     0x03 (see 2.3.3 in [SEC1]).  The public key MUST be rejected if
>     any other value is included in the first octet.
> ```

And after looking at the standard and section 2.2, Crypto++ may have a bug: its writing a `BIT STRING`, but the standard is clearly discussing a `OCTET STRING`.

**EDIT 1**: It appears this is a Crypto++ bug under [ANSI 9.62](ftp://ftp.iks-jena.de/mitarb/lutz/standards/ansi/X9/x962-11-17-97.pdf), too. Section 6.2,  Syntax for Finite Field Elements and Elliptic Curve Points (p. 20)

> ```
>     A finite field element shall be represented by a value of type FieldElement:
>       FieldElement ::= OCTET STRING
>     The value of FieldElement shall be the octet string representation of a field
>     elementfollowing the conversion routine in Section 4.3.1.
>     An elliptic curve point shall be represented by a value of type ECPoint:
>       ECPoint ::= OCTET STRING
> ```

**EDIT 2**: Crypto++ is using the format specified by Certicom's [SEC 1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://www.secg.org/collateral/sec1_final.pdf). Appendix C (page 77) states:

> ```
>     Finally, a specific field element is represented by the following type
>       FieldElement ::= OCTET STRING
>     whose value is the octet string obtained from the conversion routines
>     given in Section 2.3.5.
> ```